# Accessing an object property in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm currently working on a blog and I'm kinda stuck I need some help! 
When the user creates an article, he can set a special tag to push an article on top of the website through the property "position". So `article.position` can be equal to "first", "second", "third" or "none" (which is the default placement) depending on what the user sets.

Here is the method for creating an article with axios :

```
addArticle() {

  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/articles', {
     title: this.title,
     description: this.description,
     content: this.content,
     position: this.position,
    })

     .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
      });
   },
```

Everything is working perfectly, but here is the problem :

When a user creates an article with a special position, if an article is already set to the same position, I want it to be replaced by the new article that the user just set.

For example: 
An old Article A has `position == "first"`. The user is creating a new Article B and he wants Article B to go at the top, he sets `position == "first"`. Article A position should be now set as "none".

Important note : articles are located on a Vuex store.

Here is what I tried, in the addArticle method above the axios request :

```
if (article.position == "first") {

  let articlesList = this.$store.state.articles

  for (var i = 0; articlesList.length; i++) {
    if(articlesList[i].position == "first")
      articlesList[i].position == "none"
  }
}
```

I'm a rookie so, it might have a lot of mistakes, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (article.position === 'first') {

    let articlesList = this.$store.state.articles;

    for (i = 0; i < articlesList.length; i++) {
      if(articlesList[i].position === 'first')
        articlesList[i].position = "none"
    }
  }
```

I am just making smallest changes possible without mentioning best practices and stuff.